# Running Oracle Simple Procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, toad

I am new in Oracle, I have a following stored procedure in Oracle toad and it compiles successfully.

I want to run this procedure and see the result.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure SCOTT.sp_testing (v_date1 in date ,vno out varchar2)
As
BEGIN
select voucher_no  into vno from v_jv_ms  where v_date = v_date1;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could log the results to a table in the database. The two approaches (console vs. database) can be complementary, and both are useful in different scenarios.

Steps to achieve this:

1. Create a logging table to receive log records.
2. Create a procedure to write log output.
3. Invoke the logging procedure with the required parameters.
4. Select from the logging table to view the results.

**1. Create table to receive log output:**

```
CREATE TABLE tlog (
    seq         NUMBER(8),
    ltime       DATE,
    llevel      VARCHAR2(5),
    module      VARCHAR2(64),
    message     VARCHAR2(512)
);

CREATE SEQUENCE slog;
```

**2. Procedure to write log output:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE plog_debug(module IN VARCHAR2, message IN VARCHAR2) IS
    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tlog
        (seq, ltime, llevel, module, message)
    VALUES
        (slog.NEXTVAL, SYSDATE, 'DEBUG', module, message);
    COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        ROLLBACK;
END plog_debug;
```

**3. Invoke the logging procedure with the required parameters.**

```
plog_debug('SCOTT.sp_testing', 'Voucher no is:' || vno);
```

**4. Select from log table to view the result:**

```
SELECT * FROM TLOG;
| SEQ | LTIME               | LLEVEL | MODULE           | MESSAGE           | 
| 1   | 21/06/2012 09:49:00 | DEBUG  | SCOTT.sp_testing | Voucher no is:999 |
```

Comment: I dont understand why i have to do lot of work for just run my proc , i just want to execute my procedure by giving input parameter like in MSSQl we just write "Execute sp_testing (input para..)"

Comment: Please note: this suggestion will allow you to log from any stored procedure to a central location. If you follow the steps above, and add the line from point 3 to your stored procedure, you will see the result in tlog. You will still need to run it as normal though.

Comment: Am I understanding your question correctly? I am suddenly wondering if you also asking "how do I run the stored procedure?"

Comment: No, my question is just how to run my proc, it should be like a single line code like in mssql

Comment: Ok, I'd suggest you have a look at Datajam's answer below so. You can use his script to set your input date to whatever it needs to be, run the script in TOAD (use F5), and then evaluate the results in the Toad DBMS Output panel. My answer is prolly more than you need right now.

Answer (score 1):

Fire up SQL*Plus (or a script window in TOAD), and type or paste the following lines in:

```
set serverout on size 1000000
declare
  v_date1 date := sysdate;
  vno varchar2(100);
begin
  scott.Sp_testing(v_date1, vno);
  dbms_output.put_line(vno);
end;
/
```

Comment: Cant work.. compiles successfully but my DBMS Output window is disable

Comment: In TOAD, right-click in your editor, select Desktop Panels, enable DBMS Output.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `dbms_output.put_line` call to your procedure & you can see the output in DBMS Output tab.

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE scott.Sp_testing (v_date1 IN DATE,
                                              vno     OUT VARCHAR2)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT voucher_no
    INTO   vno
    FROM   v_jv_ms
    WHERE  v_date = v_date1;

    dbms_output.Put_line('Voucher no is:'
                         || vno);
END;
```